# Appcompat v7 Material checkbox changing color to default black in Lollipop devices

Tags: android, checkbox, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-appcompat

I am using appcompat v7 material checkbox. My project theme is light blue, so I am assigning light blue for my checkbox checked color in **styles.xml** as follows

```
<!--checked color-->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/light_blue</item> 

<!--un checked color--> 
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
```

**In My layout file**

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_tick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Everything works fine with the versions below kitkat's, but the problem arises only with lollipop versions ( By default it is automatically assigning black color ). I really dont know why it is happening. Kindly please help me with your solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you dont have another style.xml file for v21?

Comment: I think you may need `<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/light_blue</item>` for lollipop (although that could be automatic depending on which theme you inherit from)

Comment: @tyczj i dont have seperate v21 style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

> android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"

Your `CheckBox` should be styled automatically, without setting `android:button` property.

Comment: @njzk2 yes - that's why `AppCompat` is used

Comment: well that works fine @questioner. Thank you it really helped me a lot. Thank you guys njzk2 and tyczj.

Answer (score 0):

### Use AppCombat check box for best result

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
   />
```

### After this go to styles.xml and create new styles as follows

```
   <style name="SampleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/red</item>
        </style>
```

### This is not done yet go to your manifest xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme" />
```

This Works on pre_lollipop devices also. Happy coding :)